# open jPanel program by clicking html button

Tags: java, html, jpanel

It's possible to run a java program or JPanel program in html web?

For example, in my website here is a button. When I click it, it will run the java program that in the same war file. Pop a JPanel windows out and let me continues my work

Similar to when people choose to upload something, click on browser button and pop a new windows to select what to upload

Comment: No. Applets are dead.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I just want something like browse file to upload, still can't? I tried applet and know that now no browser support this

Comment: Use HTML/CSS/JavaScript instead

Comment: No need for a JPanel to upload a file to a servlet. You might find [GWT](http://www.gwtproject.org/) to your liking.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I' doing a excel to mySQL convertor... So i've use some java library for reading excel now which is not js can do

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Sorry maybe my requirement is not clear, I'm not want to do a file upload or run java inside browser, I want to make a button. When I click on the button, it will run the JPanel outside the browser and web(maybe some exe file)

Comment: And we're back to Applets are dead.

Comment: *"Similar to when people choose to upload something, click on browser button and pop a new windows to select what to upload"* - The web browser can take care of it.  Not an expert in the field, but there are number of "other ways" to fake it using CSS/Html. *"o i've use some java library for reading excel now which is not js can do"* - So, post the selected file to a web server that performs the required operations

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the stated requirement 'open JPanel from HTML button' is no longer possible.